# Higher order derivative function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

I have a question where it's given that

> $f$ is thrice differentiable and $f'(x)=x^2-x+1$ at $x = -1,0,1$ .

Then can we say that $f''(x) = 2x - 1$ and $f'''(x) = 2$ at $x= -1,0,1$?

Note: $f$ is not just thrice differentiable at $-1,0,1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I'm interpreting the questions correctly, but I'll answer based on what I understand. If $f$ is thrice differentiable and $f'(x) = x^2-x+1$ $\textit{only}$ at the values $x=-1,0,1$, then no you can't claim specific formulae for $f''$ or $f'''$. I'll show you a counter example. Suppose
$$g'(x) = \frac{x^3}{2}+x^2-\frac{3 x}{2}+1$$
everywhere (where the domain is all real numbers). Then notice that
$g'(-1) = f'(-1), g'(0)=f'(0), g'(1) = f'(1)$ i.e $g$ satisfies the same constraints that $f$ does (moreover $g$ is thrice differentiable by construction), however $g''(x)$ and $g'''(x)$ at the specific input points don't agree with the formulae you've provided.

Comment: Yes f'(x) has that value only at x = -1,0,1. Thanks for the answer.